# Criar váriavel com uma propriedade do objeto - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estou tentando criar uma váriavel para setar uma das propriedades de um objeto obtido pelo método get.

Quando dou console no subscribe recupero o valor do array, mas estou tendo dificuldade (por ser iniciante) para setar apenas uma das proprierades dos objetos desse array.

**Componente:**

```
this.mainService.getGraph()
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res) 
      this.name = res[''].map(res => res.name)
      console.log(this.name)
```

**Console.log:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque um número no lugar de ' ' aqui: res[''].map . Se resolver me avise que vou colocar como resposta.

Comment: já coloquei, da como undefined também.

Comment: Na sua pergunta não ficou muito claro. Você quer que o `this.name` receba apenas um dos nomes presentes no array? Ou receba um array como todos os nomes do array original?

Comment: um array com todos os nomes do array original. o objetivo é pegar esses valores para criar um grafico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para criar um novo array com os nomes do array original, basta usar o [método map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) direto no array:

```
this.name = res.map(it => it.name)
```

Comment: já tinha conseguido resolver, mas obrigado pela ajuda! foi exatamente o que fiz :D